# Is there something you must do when you ejaculate?

Tags: sex

Is there a ritual or prayer you must do once you ejaculate??

Comment: His Question is valid. There is a *DUA* when a man is with his wife in bed. This *DUA* is about forgiveness of bad deeds of both and asking Allah for a *Naik* and Obedient child. Sorry, I do not remember the text. And I can not search for it now.

Answer (score 2):

Assaalam alaykom

The ceremonial is to do Al-Ghusl "the complete ablution", as described [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0P4A7gE5qYE)

Comment: why down-vote ? is it wrong ? i am just trying to help because i don't knwo if the user is a new Muslim or an old one ..